# Is a constant a $ C^\infty $ function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Is the function $f(x)= t $  (where t is a constant) a $ C^\infty $ function? The derivative would be zero, and it is continous everywhere. But still a classmate of mine doesn't seem to be convinced (and to be honest, me neither).

Comment: Clearly it is by definition. Why you are not convinced?

Comment: Is $f(x) = 0$ differentiable?

Comment: The derivative of a constant is $0$, and $0$ is still a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this function does not depend on $x$, it is indeed $C^\infty$ in $x$, as it is costant (in $x$) and hence all its derivatives do exist and equal zero. Same would apply also to $f(x) = |t|$ etc.